# Linear Algebra: Projection of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I am having some confusion of this problem:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$. If $T(a,b,c)=(a,b,0)$, show that $T$ is the projection on the xy-plane along the z-axis.

The following is the definition of projection: Let $V$ be a vector space and $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$ (direct sum). A function $T: V \to V$ is called the Projection of $W_1$ along $W_2$  if for $x=x_1 +x_2$ with $x_1 \in W_1$ and $x_2 \in W_2$, we have $T(x) = x_1$.

My attempt of the solution: This is not a good definition of projection, I think. From my perspective, I said that $W_1$ = $(a,b,0)$ and $W_2$ = $(0,0,c)$. I checked that $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. I am not sure if I am following this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W_1 = \{(x,y,0) : x, y \in \Bbb{R}\}$ and $W_2 = \{(0,0,z) : z \in \Bbb{R}\}$; note $W_1$ is the $xy$-plane and $W_2$ is the $z$-axis. Let ${\bf v} = (a,b,c) \in \Bbb{R}^3$. Then ${\bf v}= (a,b,c) = (a,b,0) + (0,0,c) = {\bf v}_1 + {\bf v}_2$ where ${\bf v}_1 \in W_1$ and ${\bf v}_2 \in W_2$. From here, you find that $T{\bf v} = {\bf v}_1$, so $T$ is projection onto $W_1$ (the $xy$-plane) along $W_2$ (the $z$-axis).

Comment: Okay, so I was sort of on the right track right?

Comment: It seems you were on the right track, especially since you showed that $\Bbb{R}^3 = W_1 \oplus W_2$.

Comment: Also, another question I have is this: Find a formula for $T(a,b,c)$ where T represents the projection on the z-axis along the xy-plane. Here's what I think. If we let $W_1$ = ${ (0,0,z) | c \in {\mathbb R}}$ and $W_2$ = ${ (a,b,0) | a,b \in {\mathbb R}}$, do we find the formula based on the definition?